# SMB Client on azure server not deleting file from azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, smb

I have a flask webapp running on an Ubuntu Azure sever. I also have an azure storage account, and to access the storage from the webapp, I use SMB. This has worked so far, with adding and updating files on the server, but I tried to delete a file and it didn't work. No error or anything, it just did nothing and the file is still on the server. I tried the command locally and it worked fine. Is there something I'm doing wrong and how could I fix this problem. Here's the command I've been using:

```
smbclient //name.file.core.windows.net/website  -mSMB3 -e -Uname%password -c 'rm tempplugins/test2.ini'
```

Comment: Are you sure the Azure storage account associated with your VM via the SMB command you used?

Comment: @CharlesXu I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter what account you're using since it's SMB. I can modify files locally or from the server, but I can only delete files locally, not from the server

Comment: What do you mean that modifies the files locally? As I understand your SMB is in the remote server and mount the storage to the server.

Comment: I can modify files on the SMB server from my PC using `smbclient`. The SMB server isn't at all associated with the webapp, I just have an azure webapp and a separate azure storage account

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your exact problem, but I was attempting to perform operations on a file share on an Azure Storage Account from an Azure VM running CentOS, and I ran into several different problems.  It took me a while to get the kinks worked out.

In my case, I had to use to use backslashes, but I had to double them so that they were escaped properly. Example:

`smbclient \\\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\\sharename`

Additionally, we weren't using an integrated active directory, and so we had to use the storage account name as the username and it had to be "prefixed" with "Azure" like "Azure\storageaccount".  And don't forget that backslashes have to be doubled!  Also, the password was the storage account key. Example:

`smbclient \\\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\\sharename -U Azure\\storageaccount%key`

I used the "-d" option to debug the command line options for smbclient.  However, in my case, the "-d" option had to be on the end of the command or it interfered. If it hadn't been for the clues provided by "-d", I never would have gotten this to work.  Example:

`smbclient \\\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\\sharename -U Azure\\storageaccount%key -d`

Here's a simple, one-liner that shows a directory of a file share on an Azure Storage Account. Example:

`smbclient \\\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\\sharename -U Azure\\storageaccount%key -c dir -d`

I hope that this helps someone else as I must of blown 2 to 3 hours to get this worked out.